# How to use chart.js with jhipster project

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster, webpack-2, html-webpack-plugin

So i want to try out Chat.js with the following project.

```
https://github.com/mraible/jhipster4-demo
```

So i researched and came across the following `http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/`

So i installed ng-2 charts. ng2-charts required chart.js so I also installed chart.js and i can see it under node_modules of jhipster4-demo project.

ng2 chart says

```
Embedding Chart.js in application is mandatory!

<script src="node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>
```

How to do the above mandatory step in jhipster4-demo project ? Since i am not a webpack expert not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import your libs into `src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts`:

```
import 'chart.js/src/chart.js';
```

This is what is explained in the "Managing dependencies" section of the [README.md](https://github.com/mraible/jhipster4-demo/blob/master/README.md#managing-dependencies) file also generated in Matt Raible's demo application.

Comment: Hi.. i tried two ways. One your way and one putting the following     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script> in index.ejs and both worked.

Comment: Inserting script in index.ejs prevents you from benefitting from webpack bundle optimisations. Also, we removed index.ejs, it's now index.html, so maybe @mraible needs to update his sample app.